# $wpdb->update does not update, var_dump of data is correct

Tags: options

I have a problem with the $wpdb->update below. The var_dump data is correct but the update is not saving the data into the record of the table. Table name is wp_rdp_media_organisations. Unique field is media_org_id.

Has someone of you an idea what I do wrong here?
Thanks in advance.

```
if(isset($_POST['update_media_org'])){
//var_dump($_POST);
extract($_POST);

$media_org_id = '';
$wpdb->update( 
    $wpdb->prefix.'rdp_media_organisations', 
    array( 
        'media_org_id'      => $media_org_id,
        'company_name'      => $company_name,
        'gender'            => $gender,
        'first_name'        => $first_name,
        'last_name'         => $last_name,
        'street_address'    => $street_address,
        'zipcode'           => $zipcode,
        'visit_addres'      => $visit_addres,   
        'visit_zipcode'     => $visit_zipcode,          
        'city'              => $city,
        'country'           => $country,
        'email_address'     => $email_address,
        'telephone'         => $telephone,
        'mobile_nr'         => $mobile_nr,
        'status'            => $status,         
        'comments'          => $comments,
        'last_updated'      => date("Y-m-d H:i:s")          
    ), 
    array( 'media_org_id' => $row_id ), 
    array( 
        '%d' ,
        '%s' ,
        '%s' ,
        '%s' ,
        '%s' ,
        '%s' ,
        '%s' ,
        '%s' ,
        '%s' ,
        '%s' ,
        '%s' ,
        '%s' ,
        '%s' ,
        '%s' ,
        '%d' ,
        '%s' ,      
        '%s'            
    ) , 
    array( '%d' ) 
);
$msg = 'Record is updated sucessfully.';
}



array(17) { ["row_id"]=> string(2) "45" ["company_name"]=> string(22) "Media Bureau Lekker bv" ["gender"]=> string(4) "Male" ["first_name"]=> string(3) "Jan" ["last_name"]=> string(8) "de Vries" ["street_address"]=> string(12) "Postadres 12" ["zipcode"]=> string(6) "8923FG" ["visit_addres"]=> string(13) "Bezoekadres 4" ["visit_zipcode"]=> string(6) "8999DW" ["city"]=> string(10) "Lekkerveen" ["country"]=> string(9) "Nederland" ["email_address"]=> string(20) "info@BureauLekker.nl" ["telephone"]=> string(12) "435635464536" ["mobile_nr"]=> string(14) "33634565463456" ["status"]=> string(1) "0" ["comments"]=> string(74) "Nieuw beureau oppassen met credit geven. Betalen binnen 5 dagen is vereist" ["update_media_org"]=> string(10) "Update Now" }
```

Comment: You should include Auth checks, and avoid using the `extract` function, especially when used on `$_POST`. What was the reason for using a custom table rather than a custom post type and post meta?

Comment: The developer of this code explain to me that this is the right way todo. If there is a better way, please give me an example so I can try. The update is in admin not in front.

Comment: I spend a lot of hours testing and reading all kinds of examples. Without any result. The dump is correct but no saving into table. Does somebody maybe has a solution?

Comment: If [debugging is disabled](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress), you're gonna have a bad time.

Comment: For the future, a custom post type with post meta and taxonomies would be the WP way to do this, custom tables should be avoided ( there are situations that warrant them sometimes e.g. traffic analytics ). What is the return value of the update call?

Comment: Tom, How do I get the return value?

Comment: Debugging is set to true. Got 1 error: visit_addres change into visit_address. No errors after this change.

Comment: Found the problem: $media_org_id = ''; that results in an empty record_id. Thanks for your replies and suggestions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When the following variable is empty,

```
$media_org_id = '';
```

it results in an empty `record_id`.